# How do I get 1 for a certain range of a value?

Tags: node-editor, shaders

I want to drive a shader with a value node. If the value would be from 0.1 to 0.3, I want the output to be 1 and otherwise I want it to be 0.

I was thinking about using *Greater Than* and *Less Than*, but I can’t quite figure it out (I attach an idea I thought would work, but it doesn’t).

[image: Idea I though would work, but it doesn’t]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it with a [Color Ramp](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/color/color_ramp.html) node. Set the interpolation to Constant, bring the black stop to the position 0.3, the white stop to 0.1 and add a black stop at 0.0.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very nice :). I noticed that Fac=0,1 still outputs 0. But when I set the white stop to 0,97 it works perfectly. Probably a rounding error in the ColorRamp...

Comment: @JachymMichal Hmm yes the Color ramp node is notorious for its rounding errors (and inefficiency) since it converts values to colors and then back to values afterwards... But that's a very high margin of error even for floating point precision errors... It's definitely possible to mimic the same setup with a combination of math nodes but it would take more space in the editor :)

Answer (score 17):

In your example, it works for the given input, that is a value `0.2` produces `1` output: value is both greater than `0.1` and lesser than `0.3`, both condition nodes outputs sum up to `2` which is clamped into the `0...1` range, so becomes `1`.

[image]

However let's see what happens if your value is below the `0.1...0.3` range: it passes only one condition, but since summing `0` and `1` results in `1`, which is the same result as in previous case due to clamping in that previous case.

[image]

So *Math > Add* is an equivalent to [Logical OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction): if either of operands is True, the result is True. You need something different, [Logical AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction): if **both** of operands are True (both less than .3 and more than .1) the result is True, otherwise it's not True (False). In order to do that, replace your *Math > Add* with **Math > Multiply** - now if either of the comparison nodes will result with `0`, the other result will be multiplied by `0`, resulting, of course, with `0`. So the only way to get `1` will be to have a value both lesser than `.3` and greater than `.1`!

[image]

There's a simpler way, however, **Math > Compare** will result in `1` if you're not more than *Epsilon* away from *Value* (otherwise `0`)

[image]

In general to output `1` if input is in range `a...b`, set the *Math > Compare* this way:

- **Epsilon** = (b-a)/2
- **Value** = a + **Epsilon**

so for range `0.1 ... 0.3`:

- **Epsilon** = (0.3-0.1) / 2 = 0.2 / 2 = 0.1
- **Value** = 0.1 + 0.1 = 0.2

In simpler terms set the the *Value* to the middle of the range, and *Epsilon* to half of the range.

Comment: in my opinion this should be the right answer...because it's easier to setup and hopefully more precise.

Comment: @Chris this is a tricky thing on SE, in the end the userbase decides what it likes more - with votes. :)

Comment: i know. I just wanted to express my thinking ;)

Comment: This is exactly the way I would do it.

Comment: Oh, right, completely forgot about that :)

Comment: Oh wow, turns out Chris was right!