# Combining UV Coordinates of Multiple Objects in Geometry Nodes

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes

[image]
I'm working with multiple objects generetad in geometry nodes and I want to combine their UV coordinates. My goal is to place them side by side, ideally splitting them in half. I've managed to transform the UVs separately for each object using vector multiply or scale, but when I try to shift them using vector add, they both move together.

Is there a way to edit the UV coordinates of each object separately and then combine them in the end? For context, my example is simplified; in reality, I'm dealing with multiple objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my posts on how to read Geometry Nodes:

- [Combine two position nodes from different mesh primitives inside a geometry node tree](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/251310/60486)
- [Raycast + Align Euler to Vector. Wrong Hit Normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/253612/60486)
- [Geometry Nodes: What Does Capture Attribute Add to Geometry?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/292029/60486)
- [Understanding how "vertex of corner" works in geometry node](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/292389/60486)
- [Passing Data Into Simulation Zone](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/296223/60486)

This will give you the understanding on what's happening here: the *Store Named Attribute* node evaluates the connected field for each face corner. For corners belonging to the cylinder, the upper "UV Map" attribute exists, and the lower one doesn't (and returns $<0, 0, 0>$ values). For corners belonging to the sphere, the upper "UV Map" attribute doesn't exist (and returns $<0, 0, 0>$ values), and the lower one does. Scaling $<0, 0, 0>$ does nothing, and so scaling don't change the fact that either branch is always zero.

Adding two values (the 2nd *Vector Math: Add* node counting from the left), where one is zero, is like "ORing" - I explain it here:

[How do I get 1 for a certain range of a value?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/230249/60486)

However, when you add (the 1st *Vector Math: Add* node counting from the left) a constant value to the upper branch, now not only you shift the populated data with this value, but also override the "empty" values (zeroes) with it. This is because it is at the moment of accessing the *Cylinder* or *UV Sphere* node's socket, that the evaluator tries to access existing data, and if there's none, the 3 zeroes for $xyz$ are generated.

### The solution

Simply do the calculations here, before joining the geometry, by using two separate *Store Named Attribute* nodes with the same attribute name:

[image]